# Accessing variables from different pages in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

I have 2 different pages in my playground with a set of public variables and I want to use those variables in my other page (I have not declared any variables there). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @EnvironmentObject variable.

Go to the WindowScene file. There you can create object and pass it to root View. like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    ...
    let device = Device()
    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(device)
    ...
}
```

`environmentObject(device)` puts the device value to cash. In ContentView you can access it by define variable with EnvironmentObject wrapper like this

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var device: Device
    var body: some View{
         ...
    }
}
```

note that you don't give any name or ID to store the value. Variable type is that ID. When you change the value in one View, all the other views will receive notification and will updates itself. That is `@EnvironmentObject` wrapper for.

this is the way you can share data between Views. Yes, you also can create some Views in other Views `init()` and store them as a struct in stored property of another View and then access struct properties. Sometimes it helps to solve some performance problems, but in general it's not the way the SwiftUI works.

Playground is also able to run SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
class Counter: ObservableObject{
    @Published var currentValue = 0
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var counter: Counter
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("count is \(counter.currentValue)")
            Text("tap me")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.counter.currentValue += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
var counter = Counter()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().environmentObject(counter))
```

Comment: Does this work in Swift playground as well or just in Xcode?

Comment: if my solution helps to fix your problem, please, accept it by pushing pushing green checkbox to the left.